# Simple Role Manager and authorization In ASP.NET MVC 5 without using Identity(CustomRoleProvider)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, roles

Custom Role Provider and authorization without using Identity in ASP.NET MVC 5

Answer (score 2):

### Here is the Roles Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SN.Helios.Portal.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class RolesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Roles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var rolelist = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.RoleName).ToList().Select(rr =>
            new SelectListItem { Value = rr.RoleName.ToString(), Text = rr.RoleName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = rolelist;

            var userlist = context.Employees.OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList().Select(uu =>
            new SelectListItem { Value = uu.FullName.ToString(), Text = uu.FullName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = userlist;

            ViewBag.Message = "";

            return View();

        }

        // GET: /Roles/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }


        //
        // POST: /Roles/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Role role)
        {

            try
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                context.Roles.Add(role);
                context.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Role created successfully !";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }


        public ActionResult Delete(string RoleName)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleName.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            context.Roles.Remove(thisRole);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        //
        // GET: /Roles/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string roleName)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var thisRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleName.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(thisRole);
        }


        //
        // POST: /Roles/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Role role)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                context.Entry(role).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //  Adding Roles to a user
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context", "Context must not be null.");
            }

            Employee user = context.Employees.Where(u => u.FullName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            Role role = context.Roles.Where(u => u.RoleName.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

            AssignUserRole assignUserRole = new AssignUserRole
            {
                EmployeeId = user.EmployeeID,
                RoleId = role.RoleID
            };

            var EmpRoleToAdd = (from emprole in context.AssignUserRoles

                                where emprole.EmployeeId == user.EmployeeID && emprole.RoleId == role.RoleID

                                select emprole).FirstOrDefault();
            if (EmpRoleToAdd == null)
            {
                context.AssignUserRoles.Add(assignUserRole);
                context.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Role created successfully !";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = " This Role already exists for this user !";
            }

            // Repopulate Dropdown Lists
            var rolelist = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.RoleName).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.RoleName.ToString(), Text = rr.RoleName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = rolelist;
            var userlist = context.Employees.OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList().Select(uu =>
            new SelectListItem { Value = uu.FullName.ToString(), Text = uu.FullName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = userlist;

            return View("Index");
        }


        //Getting a List of Roles for a User
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
            {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                Employee user = context.Employees.Where(u => u.FullName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

                var roles = user.AssignUserRoles.Select(u => u.Role).Select(u => u.RoleName).ToArray();

                ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = roles;


                // Repopulate Dropdown Lists
                var rolelist = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.RoleName).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.RoleName.ToString(), Text = rr.RoleName }).ToList();
                ViewBag.Roles = rolelist;
                var userlist = context.Employees.OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList().Select(uu =>
                new SelectListItem { Value = uu.FullName.ToString(), Text = uu.FullName }).ToList();
                ViewBag.Users = userlist;
                ViewBag.Message = "Roles retrieved successfully !";
            }

            return View("Index");
        }


        //Deleting a User from A Role
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteRoleForUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            Employee user = context.Employees.Where(u => u.FullName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            Role role = context.Roles.Where(u => u.RoleName.Equals(RoleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

            var EmpRoleToDelete = (from emprole in context.AssignUserRoles

                                   where emprole.EmployeeId == user.EmployeeID && emprole.RoleId == role.RoleID

                                   select emprole).FirstOrDefault();

            if (EmpRoleToDelete != null)
            {
                context.AssignUserRoles.Remove(EmpRoleToDelete);
                context.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Role removed from this user successfully !";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "This user doesn't belong to selected role.";
            }

            // Repopulate Dropdown Lists
            var rolelist = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.RoleName).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.RoleName.ToString(), Text = rr.RoleName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = rolelist;
            var userlist = context.Employees.OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList().Select(uu =>
            new SelectListItem { Value = uu.FullName.ToString(), Text = uu.FullName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = userlist;

            return View("Index");
        }


    }
}
```

### Create Index View for Roles Controller

```
@{

                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainView.cshtml";
}
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Role Manager</h1>
    <br />
</div>

<div class="row col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">


    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Role List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 ">
                    @foreach (var role in ViewBag.Roles)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                                <strong>@role.Text </strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1">
                                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')"><a href="/Roles/Delete?RoleName=@role.Text" class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a></span> |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { roleName = @role.Text })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div> <!-- End Panel Body-->
        </div> <!-- End Panel -->

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Create A New Role</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Roles", new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    <div>
                        Role name: @Html.TextBox("RoleName")
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                }

            </div> <!--End Panel Body-->
        </div> <!--End Panel-->
    </div> <!--End First Column-->

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Add a Role to a User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAddToUser", "Roles"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    <p>User Name: @Html.DropDownList("UserName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select ...")</p>
                    <p>Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")</p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-primary" /></p>

                }
            </div> <!-- End Panel Body-->
        </div> <!-- End Panel -->


        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>List Roles for a User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("GetRoles", "Roles"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <p>
                        User Name: @Html.DropDownList("UserName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select ...")
                        <input type="submit" value="Get Roles for this User" class="btn-primary" />
                    </p>
                }

                @if (ViewBag.RolesForThisUser != null)
                {
                    <div class="alert-info">
                        <strong>Roles for this user </strong>
                        <ol>
                            @foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser)
                            {
                                <li>@s</li>
                            }
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                }
            </div> <!-- End Panel Body-->
        </div> <!-- End Panel -->

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Remove Role from User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteRoleForUser", "Roles"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                    <p>User Name: @Html.DropDownList("UserName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select ...")</p>
                    <p>Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")</p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Delete this user from Role" class="btn-primary" /></p>

                }
            </div> <!-- End Panel Body-->
        </div> <!-- End Panel -->

    </div> <!--End Second Column-->

</div>  <!--Overall Page Wrapper-->

<div class="alert-info col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>


---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Create Edit View For Roles Controller

```
@model yournamespace.Role
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainView.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Role</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Return to Role Manager", "Index")
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoleID)
    <div>
        Role name
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoleName)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

---

Create Roles and Assign to the Users

### Create Class CustomRoleProvider

Inherit CustomRoleProvider from RoleProvider class as shown below and implement abstract class.Make changes in the classes as shown below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;


namespace yournamespace.Models
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            using (var usersContext = new SNHeliosWork2017Entities())
            {
                return usersContext.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleName).ToArray();
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (var usersContext = new SNHeliosWork2017Entities())
            {

                var user = usersContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(u => u.FullName == username);
                if (user == null)
                    return new string[] { };
                return user.AssignUserRoles == null ? new string[] { } :
                  user.AssignUserRoles.Select(u => u.Role).Select(u => u.RoleName).ToArray();
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            using (var usersContext = new SNHeliosWork2017Entities())
            {
                var user = usersContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(u => u.FullName == username);
                if (user == null)
                    return false;
                return user.AssignUserRoles != null && user.AssignUserRoles.Select(
                     u => u.Role).Any(r => r.RoleName == roleName);
            }
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

### In web.config add the following code within system.web tag

```
<system.web>       
     <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogIn" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider"  type="MyProject.Models.CustomRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

The first thing to note is that I have set the enabled attribute to true so that the framework enables the role manager. Then you have to specify the defaultProvider attribute, which is used to identify the default provider if a number of providers are specified. But in this case, I am going to have only one provider CustomRoleProvider, still the default provider has to be specified. This is contained within the providers element. The clear element is used to clear all the providers stored for this application earlier, for example the default providers. Then I have defined the custom role provider by specifying the name "CustomRoleProvider", which was used in the defaultProvider attribute. This contains a number of attributes. The most important one is the type attribute where the fully-qualified name of the custom role provider is specified (MyProject.Models.CustomRoleProvider), followed by the assembly containing this type (MyProject) and the version. Note that only the type name is required and others are optional if the type is contained within the same assembly - the web application itself. Other attributes are self-explanatory and I am not going to bore you with all these details!

Use authorize attribute to authorize controllers
As,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class RolesController : Controller
{
}
```